# No SPDIF output through sound card

Tags: sound, alsa, kodi, spdif

I built a PC to serve as a home media center, and for sound opted for a asus xonar ae sound card. I tested it with the analog outputs and everything seemed fine. But when I tried to use s/pdif output the card simply refuses to produce any output (no light trough the optical output).

I checked if it was unmuted with alsamixer, tried to use passthrough with kodi with no luck, tried to test it with aplay using an ac3 file, same results without the red light. Unfortunately I hadn't had time to test the s/pdif out on a windows machine but it seems I running out of options.

I also checked if any light would come out of the s/pdif port at boot and it doesn't but this might just be the normal operation mode. As of know my only thoughts are that the card's s/pdif output might be damaged somehow?

Comment: I have the same problem with a new x570 motherboard and Ubuntu 20.04.